# How to check if the first and last character of a word are the same in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

If I have a string that's a sentence, I want to check if the first and last letter of each word are the same and find which of the words have their first and last letter the same. For example:

```
sentence_one = "Label the bib numbers in red."
```

Comment: First split into words. Then check first/last char. Which of those two things is causing a problem?

Comment: _"to find 1."_ – is there a 2.?

Comment: Furthermore, why is your string wrapped in an array? Can there be more than one string? What's your expected result for the given example?

Comment: Correct it is not an array.

Comment: Regardless of how you do it, as a first step you may wish to remove any punctuation: `"My, oh my!".gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, '')
 => "My oh my"`.

Comment: "I want to check if the first and last letter of each word are same." What does that mean? Do you wish to return an array containing words that have that property? A count of words having that property?  Display (`puts`) each word having that property? What about case? Does "Label" have that property? Note that because you stated that the string is a sentence it must contain punctuation, at least a sentence terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add one option more splitting to array (skipping one letter words):

```
sentence_one =  "Label the bib numbers in a red color"

sentence_one.split(' ').keep_if{ |w| w.end_with?(w[0].downcase) & (w.size > 1) }

#=> ["Label", "bib"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regex:

```
sentence_one = "Label the bib numbers in red"

sentence_one.scan(/(\b(\w)\w*(\2)\b)/i)
#=> [["Label", "L", "l"], ["bib", "b", "b"]]
```

`\b` is a word boundary, `\w` matches a letter (you may have to adjust this). There are 3 captures: (1) the whole word, (2) the first letter and (3) the last letter. Using `\2` requires the last letter to match the first.

Comment: What about "Label a bib numbers in red"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland left as an exercise ;-)

Comment: This is a bit advanced but much more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

This will print out all words that start with and end with the same letter (not case-sensitive)

```
sentence_one = "Label the bib numbers in red"
words = sentence_one.split(' ')

words.each do |word|
  if word[0].downcase == word[-1].downcase
    puts word
  end
end
```

Comment: Normally in Ruby you'd do this with `words.select` and move the `puts` outside of the filtering operation, perhaps chained on with `.each`

Comment: Yep, thats what I was thinking. How would I go about tallying up the total number of words that meet this parameter? Would I need to use .map to create a new array and then count? Or can I do a .split.count?

Comment: @AlfatahKader Yes `split.count` (with a block) works. See added answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment the OP asked how one could obtain a count of words having the desired property. Here's one way to do that. I assume that the desired property is that a word's first and last characters are the same, though possibly of different case. Here is a way to do that that does not produce an intermediate array whose elements would be counted.

```
r = /
    \b            # match a word break
    (?:           # begin a non-capture group
      \p{Alpha}   # match a letter
      |           # or
      (\p{Alpha}) # match a letter in capture group 1
      \p{Alpha}*  # match zero or more letters
      \1          # match the contents of capture group 1
    )             # end the non-capture group
    \b            # match a word break
    /ix           # case-indifferent and free-spacing regex definition modes

str = "How, now is that a brown cow?"

str.gsub(r).count
  #=> 2
```

See [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub), in particular the case where there is only one argument and no block is provided.

Note

```
str.gsub(r).to_a
  #=> ["that", "a"]

str.scan(r)
  #=> [["t"], [nil]]
```

Sometimes it is awkward to use `scan` when the regular expression contains capture groups (see [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan)). Those problems often can be avoided by instead using `gsub` followed by `to_a` (or [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries)).

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence_one.scan(/\S+/).select{|s| s[0].downcase == s[-1].downcase}
# => ["Label", "bib"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence_one = "Label the bib numbers in red"
puts sentence_one.split(' ').count{|word| word[0] == word[-1]} # => 1
```